# Formatting Strings 0.2 to 2000

Tags: java

How would one format the decimal number?

`0.2` to show up as `2000`.

I also want that even the value 0 would show up as `0000`

Comment: `* 10000` and `String.format`

Comment: Just for my understanding: you want 0.2000 to be printed out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question not really complete, if you want to show integer value of the decimal number (round up/down) then you just need to *10000 then round it, then format it as answered by RC .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    float original = 0.2f;
    float multiplied  = original *10000;
    int intvalue = (int)multiplied; // you can change to round up/down

    String d = String.format("%04d", intvalue);
    System.out.println("Value d : "+d);

}
```

Check here for the format https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution assuming that the desired output is 2000:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.4f", 0.2).replaceFirst("^0\\.", ""));
```

Same for 0000:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.4f", 0.0).replaceFirst("^0\\.", ""));
```

You could use a method for that:

```
private static String convert(double v) {
    return String.format("%.4f", v).replaceFirst("^0\\.", "");
}
```

Comment: I need 2000 to be outputted from 0.2 and 0000 to be outputted from 0